# I get this error when i create a new project in android studio:

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, constraints, render

when I create a new project in android studio I get this error in constraint layout:[image] and I can not add a widget to my layout

how I can solving this problem???

Comment: Try opening a no activity project

Comment: check in details what is showing there? also must be sure about gradle build complete for this.